# script.sh run differently when manually opening terminal and when using .desktop launcher

Tags: unity, command-line, bash, launcher, scripts

I have a script file `script1.sh` as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

cd /home/userA/scripts

. r1.sh
```

when I manually open a terminal and run it using `. script.sh` it works fine.

But when I created the below .desktop launcher to run it says that `ROSRUN command not found`.

This is the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Version=1.0 
Type=Application 
Terminal=true 
Icon[en_AU]=/home/userA/Pics/pic1.png 
Name[en_AU]=automatic 
Exec=/home/userA/Desktop/script1.sh 
Comment[en_AU]=comment 
Name=automatic 
Comment=comment 
Icon=/home/userA/Pics/pic1.png
```

And this is how `r1.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
rosrun r1 r1 \ 
-p1 $p1 \ 
-p2 $p2 \ 
-p3 $p3
```

So if anyone could please advise what may be the reason behind this happening. As I don't know why it runs smoothy without this error appearing when manually opening a terminal and running it, and why the error appears when I use `.desktop` launcher instead?

Comment: I assume r1.sh is located in the same directory as script1.sh is. If so, Use the full path in script1.sh, else it won't be found.

Comment: @the_Seppi sorry, I forgot to put the cd command . So no, they are not on the same path.

Comment: What happens if you **execute** script1.sh instead of **sourcing** it?

Comment: as shown in the.desktop file I'm using `Exec=/home/userA/Desktop/script1.sh ` what do you want me to do?

Comment: Run exactly the command after the `Exec=`. And your desktop file seems to lack a `[` in the first line, if this isn't a C&P mistake.

Comment: the problem is running it with the .desktop launcher not the opposite. When I manually open a terminal and source it, it works fine. I'm trying to know why it doesn't using .desktop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17382/discussion-between-the-seppi-and-user1460166).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found out in a chat with the asker, `rosrun` is a command he defined in his `.bashrc`.

Add the same definition for rosrun to your `script1.sh` and it should work.